# opencv SIFT Feature Matching is not accurate

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I am using the SIFT feature (using the following) code for traffic sign recognition. but the results are very strange:

```
#here I read 7 traffic sign images and compute the corresponding SIFTs (speed limit)
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
import glob
imglist = [[], [], [], []]
for filename in glob.glob('data/*.jpg'): #assuming gif
    base=os.path.basename(filename)
    file=os.path.splitext(base)[0]
    print (file)
    imglist[0].append(file)
    img=cv2.imread(filename)
    imglist[1].append(img)    

    img = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128))

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray=cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
    keypoints, des = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
    imglist[2].append(keypoints)
    imglist[3].append(des)
```

Some of My figures are shown below:

[image: 20km]
[image: 50km]

[image: 30km]
Then, I upload one figure, compute the SIFT and compare it with my database (the above figures) using the following code:

```
img=cv2.imread("50_test.jpg")
#img=crop_img
img = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128))
IMAGES=imglist
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
# Find the keypoint descriptors with SIFT
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray=cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
_, des = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
if des is None:
    print ("Unknown")
    #return "Unknown", 0
if len(des) < 5:
    print ("Unknown")
    #return "Unknown", 0

biggest_amnt = 0
biggest_speed = 0
cur_img = 0
for _ in IMAGES[0]:
    des2 = IMAGES[3][cur_img]
    matches = bf.knnMatch(des,des2, k=2)
    matchamnt = 0
    # Apply ratio test
    matchamnt = 0
    for m,n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.6*n.distance:
            matchamnt += 1

    print (matchamnt)
    print (IMAGES[0][cur_img])
    print ("************************")


    if matchamnt > biggest_amnt:
            biggest_amnt = matchamnt
            biggest_speed = IMAGES[0][cur_img]

    cur_img += 1
```

The figure that I upload for test is the following figure:

[image: 50test]

For the above figure the output of my code is below:

```
    similarity: 1
    10 km
    ************************
    similarity:3
    100 km
    ************************
    similarity: 1
    120 km
    ************************
    similarity: 7
    20 km
    ************************
    similarity: 6
    30 km
    ************************
    similarity: 2
    50 km
    ************************
    similarity: 4
    90 km
    ************************
    Output 20 km
```

As you can see my test image is 50 km, but suprisingly it is more similar to 20km traffic sign in my DB!!! I am wondering why is that? Any suggestion to improve the code? Tnx

Answer (score 0):

The 20 and 30 sign and your query image both share the same black border around the red circle and use a much bolder font than the 50 sign in your database, which is why they share more similar SIFT features.

You can easily solve this problem by using a package for OCR (optical character recognition) and detecting the text in the images.